# Apache site loads in Safari but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: macos, apache

I've got a local Apache server running for web development on my Mac running 10.14 Mojave. I've followed [this rather excellent guide](https://mallinson.ca/posts/5/the-perfect-web-development-environment-for-your-new-mac) to set up a local vhost setup aliasing all `.dev` sites to my local server so I can access my `example` site at `example.dev`.

This used to work just fine. Since I've upgraded OSX to Mojave, I can no longer access these sites via Chrome or Firefox. I try to access `http://example.dev` and instead loading the site, the browser instantly redirects to `https://example.dev` **(note the s!)** and it tells me the server refused to connect.

For fun, I tried using `curl` to see if the sites would load there- (they do!). I've also tried loading the sites in Safari (they do!).

So what seems to be going on is that Chrome and Firefox are getting a 307 redirect from `http` to `https`, but Safari is not.

I've checked my Apache httpd.conf (and the files it imports) and I can't find anything about redirecting.

Clearing the cache or using an incognito window does not change anything.

Does anyone have any insight into what could be going on here? I've checked my httpd.conf files and I'm not seeing anything that would be causing this- and the fact that it's affecting certain browsers but not others is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: The `.dev` TLD was recently defined, and Chrome and Firefox now require it to use HTTPS. Turns out the guide I was working off of was even updated to reference this:

> Previous versions of this tutorial used .dev as a local TLD but .dev
>   has been registered for use by Google and forced by Chrome to use SSL,
>   so it is no longer an option for local development. The .test TLD is
>   now reserved for development use. You can also use .localhost or
>   .example. You can even make up your own as long as it’s not a real TLD
>   in use.